# Error while uploading to S3 from Hadoop using s3a

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I am running a java application on kubernetes which upload multiple files from local container to s3 bucket using s3a, but I am getting the below exception in logs and files are not getting uploaded to s3.

Partial files are getting uploaded to s3

```
   2021-11-30 12:28:44,529 614982 [secor-threadpool-1] ERROR c.pinterest.secor.uploader.Uploader - Error while uploading to S3 : java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: copyFromLocalFile(/tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate, s3a://prod-dataplatform-hive/orc_secor_test/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate) on /tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: copyFromLocalFile(/tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate, s3a://prod-dataplatform-hive/orc_secor_test/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate) on /tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.FutureHandle.get(FutureHandle.java:34)
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.Uploader.uploadFiles(Uploader.java:117)
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.Uploader.checkTopicPartition(Uploader.java:244)
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.Uploader.applyPolicy(Uploader.java:284)
        at com.pinterest.secor.consumer.Consumer.checkUploadPolicy(Consumer.java:141)
        at com.pinterest.secor.consumer.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:133)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: copyFromLocalFile(/tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate, s3a://prod-dataplatform-hive/orc_secor_test/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate) on /tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.HadoopS3UploadManager$1.run(HadoopS3UploadManager.java:63)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: copyFromLocalFile(/tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate, s3a://prod-dataplatform-hive/orc_secor_test/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate) on /tmp/secor_data/message_logs/backup/7_22/DAPI_UNICAST_BOOKING_ACTION/driverapi_transactional_ha/dapi_unicast_booking_action/dt=2021-11-29/hr=12/pk_1_1_00000000000000101414.deflate: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(S3AFileSystem.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.moveFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2307)
        at com.pinterest.secor.util.FileUtil.moveToCloud(FileUtil.java:206)
        at com.pinterest.secor.uploader.HadoopS3UploadManager$1.run(HadoopS3UploadManager.java:61)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.unwrapExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:286)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.rethrowExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:265)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadImpl.waitForUploadResult(UploadImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerCopyFromLocalFile(S3AFileSystem.java:2099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(S3AFileSystem.java:2037)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;)V
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3DataSource$Utils.cleanupDataSource(S3DataSource.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1863)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1817)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:169)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:149)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:115)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:45)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this is a bug](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/952).

> problems caused by AWS SDK classes from the localstack-utils-fat.jar overriding classes defined in the actual Lambda jar/zip itself.

Here's the version you need [with the fix](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/pull/2378).  It sounds like there is a work around:

> implemented a partial fix for this that moved the localstack-utils-fat.jar later on the classpath, but this fix only applied to lambdas being run using the docker executor.

Basically, it's not your fault.  It's a code issue with dependencies overwriting each others function signatures.  You need to use the latest localstack-utils-fat.jar and it should fix your issue.

Comment: I am not using localstack-utils-fat.jar anywhere in my code

Comment: Ah, then it's likely a dependency of something you are using.  I'm going to guess that it's the s3a (and something else) that conflicting.  That likely means you need to become really aware of what versions of S3a that you are using.  Try upgrading/downgrading to try and Avoid the conflict that's clearly present.  You can also try re-ordering your dependency imports to try and help it resolve without  changing versions. (If you have that ability)

Comment: This issue is solved. You were right @matt, there is a dependency conflict for s3a. In the pom.xml file I have used both `aws-java-sdk-bundle` as `hadoop-aws` which internally have `aws-java-sdk-bundle` but of different versions.

I removed the external `aws-java-sdk-bundle` dependency which is the cause of the conflict and it works.

Comment: always debug transitive dependencies ! with gradle ``gradle dependencies`` allow to see who is using what version